# Image in background and should take available space in HTML

Tags: css, html

I have two images, one should be in the center of the box, and another image should take all available space. I have done code here, but background image is occupying all available place. Please check the code below and let me know how to solve.

```
<style>
    .img1 {
        position: relative;
        top: 50%;
        left: 50%;
    }
   .img2{
      background-image:url(html2.jpg);
     }
</style>
<body>

    <div id="mainDiv">
        <div id="innerDiv" style="padding: 10px">
            <div class="leftDiv">
                <span>
                    <img class="img1" src="html1.jpg" width="200" height="200" >
                    Place Fist image here. Place image in centre of parent with 200x200 </span>
            </div>
            <div class="rightDiv">
                <div class=img2">Place 2nd image as background and should take all space available</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Were you drunk when asking this question? Are the DIVs on seperate sides? Do they have their own widths?

Comment: your img2 class doesn't have opening " `class=img2"`

Comment: Not making fun of you - serious question. Are you diagnosed dyslexic? Your question is a bit difficult to follow with the typos. Maybe clean it up a bit so you get more people taking your question seriously. Cheers.

Comment: It would be useful to knwo what this is **supposed** to look like. Dpo you have an images of  the intended result?

Answer (score 0):

I think you're missing "height" on "img2" so you can see the img on bg... Cause if you dont, img2 will only show bg behind the text. Leave you a fiddle but not so sure what you want to make

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nvche2po/)

```
.img2{
 height: 100vh;
 background-size: 100% 100%;
  background-image:url(http://www.fonbruno.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/placeholder-1000x1000.jpg);
 }
```